# transform ExecuteSQL record in Apache Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am a newbie to Nifi so lack still in learning this too. I have a task to get data from executeSQL and the record return like this:

```json
[{
  "PKG_HA_01_ON":2.0,
  "PKG_HA_03_ON":28.0,
  "PKG_HA_04_ON":7.0,
  "PKG_HA_05_ON":0.0,
  "PKG_HA_06_ON":1.0,
  "PKG_HA_09_ON":5.0
 },
 {
  "PKG_HA_01_ON":8.02905,
  "PKG_HA_03_ON":57.29038333333333,
  "PKG_HA_04_ON":2.2858666666666663,
  "PKG_HA_05_ON":60.0,
  "PKG_HA_06_ON":12.291533333333332,
  "PKG_HA_09_ON":12.3363
}]
```

This is the result of a union query. Now, I would like to convert into this:

```json
[{
   "machine":"PKG_HA_01_ON",
   "counter":2.0,
   "duration":8.02905
 },
 {
   "machine":"PKG_HA_03_ON",
   "counter":28.0,
   "duration":57.29038333333333
}]
```

I have researched on JoltTransformJSON but still stuck with it. So what is the best way to achieve desired JSON?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consecutively apply **shift** transformation as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@PKG_HA_01_ON": "PKG_HA_01_ON.&",
        "@PKG_HA_03_ON": "PKG_HA_03_ON.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "&.machine",
        "@(1,&.0)": "&.counter",
        "@(1,&.1)": "&.duration"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Restrict the result set to two keys(`PKG_HA_01/3_ON`) in the first step while determining the values for the keys `0` and `1` respectively, then convert those numbered keys to yours (`counter` and `duration` respectively) while adding the `machine` element, and remove the key names at the last step.